# inaccessible directory

Tags: command-line, directory, path, git

I git cloned into a directory "/source" before I `mkdir`ed it. It did not show up in its parent directory, but when I run the `ls` command, the output is indented like this:

```
    database  static  superlists  virtualenv
```

instead of:

```
database  static  superlists  virtualenv
```

When I run the `tree` command, the structure looks like this:

```
.
├──  
│   └── source
│       ├── functional_tests
│       │   └── __pycache__
│           └── __pycache__
├── database
├── static
├── superlists
│   ├── functional_tests
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ├── lists
```

See the gap? It should be in . along with database, static, superlists, etc.

I cannot `cd` into source from its parent directory either.

What did I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

This is on ubuntu 14.04 lts server.

One of the challenges of this is the difficulty in describing it, which makes it hard to search for.

**edit:** the simplest explanation was correct, I created a directory named "  ". I removed it using backslash key to escape.

Comment: It looks like you created a directory whose name consists entirely of whitespace - it should just be a matter of renaming it (using suitable escaping/quoting)

Comment: yup, cded into with backslash to escape. I thought this was the most simple solution, but I tried it a couple times and failed, so I figured it's more complicated.

Should I leave my question up for other newbies?

Comment: What does `ls -p | sed -n l` give?

Answer (score 1):

You have managed to create a directory with a space (or several) as its name.

Rename it:

```
mv " "* I_see_you
```

In the case that it's not a simple space, you could try replacing any non graphical characters with `X`:

```
$ # (having moved everything else away to a safe place...)
$ for d in *; do test -d "$d" && echo mv "$d" "$( tr -c '[:graph:]' 'X' <<<"$d" )"; done
```

Remove `echo` to actually perform the `mv`.

Comment: It may not necessarily be a space character. Try after `mkdir $'\ua0' $'\u2006' $'\u301' ...`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Solved it in a possibly heavy-handed way, but it covers the cases you gave me.

Comment: Note that both `$'\u301'` (combining acute accent, whether it's visible depends on the terminal and whether it follows a character (and for xterm if there exists a combined form of the resulting character) and `$'\ua0'` (non-breaking space) **are** `[:graph:]`s. The reason it seems to somehow work for you is because of a [bug/limitation of GNU `tr`](/a/228570).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a directory whose name consists entirely of non-printable and whitespace characters.

You can use a wildcard to match it:

```
mv -i [^A-Za-z0-9_]* renamed
```

This prompts you to move all files whose name don't begin with a letter, a digit or an underscore. There's probably only that one file.

Alternatively, if your shell is set up to iterate through completions, type `mv` <kbd>Space</kbd> then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> until the right file is inserted on the command line. In bash, this is not the default, you need to have `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` in your `~/.inputrc` or `bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'` in your `~/.bashrc` (or other methods such as binding a key to `menu-complete`).